# Android improperly forgets wireless networks

Tags: android, wireless

I've written an application to easily connect Android devices to our company's various wireless networks. It is intended to be run once, when the device is unboxed and set up with the rest of our application suite.

The problem is that sometimes, the device will forget the networks without being told to do so. I have not been able to reproduce this, unfortunately. I'm hoping that I've missed some API call that the Android gurus here can help me find.

The code that follows is from my run-once wireless initialization app, with the network names and keys changed. Can anyone see something I'm doing incorrectly here?

Edit: The device that I have observed this behavior on is the LG Ally. I'm hoping it's a bug with my own code, so that's where I'm starting.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    WifiConfiguration n1Config = new WifiConfiguration();
    n1Config.SSID = "\"networkOne\"";
    n1Config.preSharedKey = "\"...\"";
    n1Config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

    WifiConfiguration n2Config = new WifiConfiguration();
    n2Config.SSID = "\"networkTwo\"";
    n2Config.hiddenSSID = true;
    n2Config.wepKeys[0] = "...";
    n2Config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    n2Config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    n2Config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    n2Config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    n2Config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
    n2Config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
    n2Config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    n2Config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    n2Config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    n2Config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    n2Config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    n2Config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    n2Config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    int n1ID = wifiManager.addNetwork(n1Config);
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(n1ID, false);

    int n2ID = wifiManager.addNetwork(n2Config);
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(n2ID, false);
}
```

Comment: Could it be something as simple as there may be a finite number of networks that Android can remember? Example, Android will only remember X number of networks and under certain circumstances if a user goes within range of X networks since last using your company network, your network gets pushed out of the network 'cache'. Admittedly it seems unlikely but could be tested fairly easily.

Comment: Are you sure someone didn't tell it to forget it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to call wifi.saveConfiguration(); after you have added both of your configurations to the WifiManager.

Comment: Ugh, an inexcusable miss. This is almost certainly my problem. I'll do some testing. Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: Okay. Let me know if that ends up being the solution. I am getting started in Android development myself.